# Show that a matrix A may have all leading principal minors greater or equal to zero, yet not be positive semi-definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Title says it all, but I'll rephrase it to be clear.

A is an $n\times n$ matrix whose leading principal minors are all greater than or equal to zero.

A leading principal minor is the determinant of the k-th submatrix of A, consisting of the first k rows and k columns of A.

Show that matrix A can satisfy this conditions yet also not be positive semidefinite.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it includes $det(A)\geq 0$?

Comment: yes it does include that

Comment: Then I think its impossible, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: I will have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0  \\
0 & -1 \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you. A hint is actually a lot more useful to me.